# In rxjs, is there an overhead for using a BehaviorSubject to store data vs a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

If I have a lot of data, and I want to persist it in a singleton service in modern Angular, for example, will there be a memory or other kind of perf penalty for storing the data as BehaviorSubjects like this:

`property = new BehaviorSubject(lotsOfData)`

instead of persisting lotsOfData itself as the value of a property:

`property = lotsOfData`

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: To get a proper answer, you should provide info on a) what kind of data structure you want to store and b) what you plan to do with the data / the object.

Comment: Basically I want a name-value data store, sort of like a simplified version ngrx. So the question I had with a colleague is whether there is a perf penalty for storing static data (name value pairs) as Behavior Subjects rather than straight data, persisted in the singleton store service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.5/src/BehaviorSubject.ts) class is really compact. All it does is storing current value as private property, which is also available as public `value` read-only property.

It has virtually no overhead and doesn't process values, so the amount of data doesn't matter.